# 3D interpolation of pollutants across water depth

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, 3d, interpolation, software-recommendations

I have point data representing tissue sampling performed by NOAA NCCOS for Gulf of Maine waters. I am assuming a temporal resolution of one sampling point per location for one year. I have searched for literature to address how to interpolate this data across water depth, but have yet to come to a conclusion.

A simple kriging shows patterns of overlay, which as a simplified approach, is fine. Are there more refined methods to determine the distribution of pollutants using marine tissue samples? I would prefer methods that have been published or applied.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2 and I am open to any open source software. I am also proficient in Python and ArcObjects.

Comment: are you looking to do 3D interpolation?

Comment: sorry about that, edited @PolyGeo

Comment: @mapBaker, I am open to 2D or 3D, 3D is not necessary to my extended analysis, but would be more precise.

Comment: @albaba726 I only ask because you mention "how to interpolate this data across water depth", which to me means 3D interpolation... which I'm not sure how you do! You might want to look into some software designed for Marine Interpolation like Surfer http://www.goldensoftware.com/products/surfer

Comment: @mapBaker, really unsure as to why this is on hold. your answer fits my question. If you are able, please post the answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @alybab726 looks like because its on hold I can't submit an answer... but super glad you got what you were after! Maybe if you re-worded your question to ask about 'methods to do 3D marine interpolation' ??? or something similar it would be released?

Comment: @alybaba726 you should try the program Surfer for 3D interpolation... http://www.goldensoftware.com/products/surfer